# How do I display a saved treemap object? MWE included?

Tags: r, plot, treemap

This may be a silly question but does anyone know how to display a treemap object after it's generated in R? Consider the code below:

```
loadpackages <-function(package.list = c("ggplot2", "Rcpp")) {new.packages <-package.list[!(package.list %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
    if (length(new.packages))
      install.packages(new.packages, repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')
    lapply(eval(package.list), require, character.only = TRUE)}
loadpackages(c("treemap"))

data(GNI2014)
tm = treemap(
  GNI2014,
  index = c("continent", "iso3"),
  vSize = "population",
  vColor = "GNI",
  draw = FALSE, # comment this line out to see the treemap
  type = "value"
)
```

This produces no graphic but it saves a "treemap list". Does anyone know how I can display this object?

PS: My motive is to modify some categorical labels (add percents) after producing a particular tree map but I'm unable to do generate a plot in the display from the treetop object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source code it does not appear to store enough information to allow re-drawing. The `treemap()` is meant to be called for it's plotting side effects. Given that, I have no idea why they have a `draw=FALSE` option if there is no way to plot it later.

Even though the official function doesn't allow it, you could hack the function. We can modify the function to return all the parameters it was passing to draw. Here's a version tested with `treemap_2.4-1`

```
treemap2 <- treemap
drawcall <- body(treemap)[[c(85,3,2)]]
drawcall[[1]] <- quote(list)
savelist <- as.list(body(t2)[[c(90,3)]])
savelist[["drawparam"]] <- drawcall
body(treemap)[[c(90,3)]] <- as.call(savelist)
```

Then you can call the function like before

```
tm <- treemap2(
  GNI2014,
  index = c("continent", "iso3"),
  vSize = "population",
  vColor = "GNI",
  draw = FALSE,
  type = "value"
)
```

And now all the parameters used to draw the function are stored in `tm$drawparam`. It uses a hidden function `tmDrawRect` to do all the drawing but you can call that with

```
do.call(treemap:::tmDrawRect, tm$drawparam)
```

using the data stored in the object. If you change any data in `tm$drawparam` that should directly effect the plot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent work on this. Not only did you solve my quandary, your solution taught me how to reference function internals. If you ever visit DC please let me know, you've earned a *free lunch*.